# How to define a custom SBT task that takes a File argument and returns a File?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm working on a Scala project that requires I compute the base64-encoded SHA-256 hash of a jar file produced with `sbt-assembly`.  I have written a simple Scala method to accomplish this:

```
    def computeCodeHash(file: File): File = {
     //..do some work and write the hash to a new file with a '.sha256' extension
    }
```

Now I need to create an SBT command that I can invoke to compute this hash.  I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
    > codehash "target/scala-2.11/foo.jar"
```

and have that task call my `computeCodeHash` method.  For extra bonus automation points, I'd also like to figure out how to extend the build so that the `assembly` task created by the `sbt-assembly` plugin also runs my `computeCodeHash` method.

I've tried reading through the docs on input tasks and settings and parsers, but my knowledge of SBT is limited and I'm unable to figure out how to accomplish what seems like a pretty basic task.  I also tried reading the `sbt-assembly` source code, but I couldn't make heads or tails of it.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?:

```scala
import sbt.Keys._
import sbt._
import sbtassembly.AssemblyKeys._

object Build extends sbt.Build {


  private def mkHash(pathToFile:String) : String = {
    println(s"make a hash here for: $pathToFile")
    "??"
  }

  lazy val codehash = inputKey[Option[String]]("Mk hash")


  val codehashTask = codehash := {
    val s = streams.value
    val args = sbt.complete.Parsers.spaceDelimited("<arg>").parsed
    args.headOption.map{ path =>
      s.log.info(s"make a hash for: $path")
      mkHash(path)
    }
  }

  lazy val root = Project("sbt-hash-task", file("."))
      .settings(
        codehashTask,
        (assembly) := {
          val out = assembly.value
          mkHash(out.getAbsolutePath)
          out
        }
      )

}
```

Usage:

```
sbt
> codehash some/path.jar
> assembly //runs assembly and codehash
```

Comment: Thanks @ed, I had something similar but not so idiomatic and I couldn't figure out how to get the task integrated with `assembly`.  Note that I did find in DefaultParsers a fileParser, which is useful because allows tab completion to know that the argument is a file path relative to the base directory.